# Modelica Example MoonLanding

Tags: modelica, dymola

i'm trying to learn modelica and started with coding some simple examples from the tutorial:"Introduction to Object-Oriented Modeling and Simulation with 
OpenModelica" by Peter Fritzson [Link](https://www.modelica.org/events/modelica2006/Proceedings/tutorials/Tutorial1.pdf) . I'm working with dymola.
There is one example called Moon Landing which i can't get running.
After starting the Simulation i can't plot any of the variables.
Here is my code:

```
model Example

class Rocket "rocket class"
  parameter String name;
  Real mass(start = 1038.3);
  Real altitude(start = 59404);
  Real velocity(start = -2003);
  Real thrust;
  Real acceleration;
  Real gravity;
  parameter Real massLossRate=0.000277;
equation 
  acceleration = (thrust-mass*gravity)/mass;
  der(mass) = -massLossRate * abs(thrust);
  der(altitude)=velocity;
  der(velocity)=acceleration;
end Rocket;

class CelesticalBody
  constant  Real   g = 6.672e-11;
  parameter Real   radius;
  parameter String name;
  parameter Real   mass;
end CelesticalBody;

class MoonLanding
  parameter Real force1 = 36350;
  parameter Real force2 = 1308;
 protected 
  parameter Real thrustEndTime = 210;
  parameter Real thrustDecreaseTime = 43.2;
 public 
  Rocket          apollo(name="apollo13");
  CelesticalBody  moon(name="moon",mass = 7.382e22, radius=1.738e6);
equation 
    apollo.thrust = if (time < thrustDecreaseTime) then force1
                  else if 
                         (time < thrustEndTime) then force2
                  else 0;
   apollo.gravity = moon.g*moon.mass/(apollo.altitude+moon.radius)^2;
end MoonLanding;


end Example;
```

Does someone knows where a mistake could be?

Comment: It works for me (I copied your code and simulated the class MoonLanding for 230 seconds). I have access to all variables. Can you see the classes (apollo, moon) on the simulation tab?

Comment: Hey, thank you for you answer.
I allways tried to simulate the whole model containing all classes.
But i have to simulate just the MoonLanding class.
Any idea why it doesn't work when simulating the whole model?

Comment: The whole "model" is actually a "package" containing three "models". Models, packages, blocks etc. are special Modelica classes.

Answer (score 2):

As @Rene-Just-Nielsen indicated you have to simulate Example.MoonLanding and you should make Example a package (not model), and MoonLanding (Rocket, CelestialBody) model (not class):

```
package Example
  model Rocket "rocket class" 
    ...
  end Rocket;
  model CelestialBody 
    ...
  end CelestialBody
  model MoonLanding 
    ...
  end MoonLanding;
end Example;
```

(Basically the answer isn't mine but Rene's, and I agree with it.)

Some additional benefits of marking them as "package" and "model" are that:

- Attempting to simulate a package (such as `package Example`) will give an error in Dymola, so this particular error would be detected.
- The package browser is intended to show the contents of packages - not models.
- MoonLanding uses `time`, but only models and blocks can use `time` (this is just given as a warning).